# How to add cells in row in axlsx in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I create row in aslsx and now I want to add cells in existing row.

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Buttons") do |sheet|

sheet.add_row ['Categories:']
@categories.each do |category|
  // Here I want to add this category name existing row
end
```

If I wrong please correct me also

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to add all categories to the same row, this should work:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

categories = ['Categories:'] + @categories.pluck(:name)

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Buttons") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row categories
end
```

I assume your Category model have an attribute called name, if not, just change `:name` to something more appropriate. Method `add_row` receives an array with values and writes everything from the array to the current row, thus you need to fill the array with the names of your categories first. Then, you can pass the array to the method `add_row` and it will fill entire row in excel with categories.

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) you can find more about `pluck` method. Or just in rails console, try `Category.all.pluck(:id)` and you will get an array filled with IDs of all your categories.